# Trying to understand SqlParameterCollection.Add() size parameter for strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to understand the `size` parameter in [SqlParameterCollection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx)() method. Simply reading:

> The size as an Int32.

Doesn't really help.

Say, my SQL Server table column is defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
  ([col1] NVARCHAR(5))
```

So when I'm adding a new row to that table:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable ([col1]) " +
    "VALUES (@strCol1)";

string strValue = "abcdef";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, connection))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@strCol1", SqlDbType.NText, 5).Value =
         strValue;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

What value will be added to my `col1` column? Or will `cmd.Parameters.Add` throw an exception?

Comment: I wonder why you down voted the answer while the answer guides you to correct documentation and you can see that **"then the value will be truncated to match the size."**

Comment: @RezaAghaei: The person whose answer I marked didn't give me a link to a wordy MS doc but explained it in a simple language.

Comment: The link guides you to understand the `Size` property and specially when you say "The size as an Int32. Doesn't really help." means you need more description, not only the bottom line answer :)

Comment: I think down voting such an answer may mislead users and you can leave a comment instead of down vote for such a correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get no exceptions and "abcde" will be inserted into your table

Comment: Thank you for explaining it.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a complete documentation for [`SqlParameter.Size`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size(v=vs.110).aspx) Property.

Based on documentation you can see **The value will be truncated to match the size** and you will not receive an exception.

Comment: I wonder why you down voted the answer while the answer guides you to correct documentation and you can see that **"then the value will be truncated to match the size."**